# Retrieving data faster from SQL database with hibernate

Tags: java, performance, hibernate

My application contains a lot of data in the database.
Everyday we are processing around 60K records.

My problem is, since the data is growing everyday is there a way to make the user generated searches from my application faster as it takes quite a bit of time to load the records on to the UI. I am using Java with Spring and Hibernate.

I am trying to improve the user experience as we are getting lots of complaints from the users about the searches being slow.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: How are you getting data from the database? show us some code

Comment: As other people already pointed out, the first step is to take a look at your application, try to identify the point where your code spends the most time and optimize accordingly.

If you still do not achieve the needed performance, after trying everything else, you could have a look at other database technologies, just to hold a search index. Cassandra for example seems excellent for search-indexes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple answer to this.  It boils down to looking at your application, its schemas and the queries that are generated, and figuring out where the bottlenecks are.  Depending on that, the solution might be:

- to add indexes to certain tables,
- to redesign parts of the data model or the queries,
- to reduce the size of the resultsets you are reading (e.g. to use paging),
- to make user queries simpler, or
- to do something else.